# PHP - email form POSTs empty variables (RewriteEngine Off)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

I've spent over two days on this problem including this community. Still can't figure out what the reason of the problem is.

1) My form first line definition:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="/mail/sendemail.php">
```

All input elements have '**name**' param defined.

2) I changed **sendemail.php** file permission to **755**.

3) My htaccess file does not include RewriteEngine flag, it is as follows:

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess .htpasswd */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
DirectoryIndex index.html
AddHandler php5.5-fastcgi php
```

Actually - I copied this htaccess file from my other website where different email form works well.

4) I tried to modify sendemail.php multiple times. 
I excluded any validation functions like empty, trim, etc - tried simple: `$from = $_POST['email'] - no additional validation` - still does not work.

5) sendemail.php:

```
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'changed@changed.com';

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'. "\r\n".
           'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n".
           'From: '.$name."\r\n".
           'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n".
           'Subject: '.$subject."\r\n".
           'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
die;
```

6) Mail is being sent but with no From, Subject and Message - those values are empty.

7) This is simple one-page website with contact form and only this one php script.

In most articles I can read that RewriteEngine is usually responsible for this error - but I use absolute path `/mail/sendemail.php` and I have no RewriteEngine flag in my htaccess file defined.

**UPDATE.**

8. In original sendemail.php script there is an array variable that is used to create $headers - BUT - there is an information in my server's log, that this array (type) cannot be used as 4th parameter in mail function. I decided to create $headers in different way as I already mentioned above. Maybe this array should be converted into something that could be accepted as 4th parameter in mail function?

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
```

Comment: Have you dumped your variables?  Are they what you'd expect?  Have you tried sending without the additional headers parameter?

Comment: It's generally bad practice to use @ before an action. If you don't want errors coming use some defensive programming and check that your POST vars are set with `isset` or other.

Comment: @Progrock - if additional headers parameter was the cause (its construction), at least $message should be sent correctly because this is not a part of headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that finally works:

```
<?php

$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'valid-address@valid-domain.com';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
           "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n".
           "From: $name\n".
           "Reply-To: $from\n".
           "Subject: $subject\n".
           "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 
    // Back to previous page
    "<script>
        alert('Dziękuje za przesłanie wiadomości. Postaram się odpowiedzieć możliwie szybko.');
        window.history.go(-1);      
     </script>";

die;
?>
```

Thank You for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
           "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n".
           "From: $name\n".
           "Reply-To: $from\n".
           "Subject: $subject\n";`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it did not help. It means that at this moment in code my POST variables are empty.